# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, email

I'm trying to get my course HTML code from my database and then emailing it to my user. I'm using Rapid API for this. My code checks if courseLoop is the same as the "course", if true it runs through **.done** and runs the sendEmail() function when the day of dataHTMLMain == 1 or 2 or 3 and so on..

The sendEmail() checks if any of the users have the same course that courseLoop is in. If yes (goes through **.done()**) and sends the email to the users. Once the email is sent to the users it all so updates the users day by 1. This is where I'm facing a problem.

Also, if I manually make it:

**- "email": dataMain[0].email, 

 - "day": (parseInt(dataMain[0].day) + 1),**

it works.

The error I'm getting is:

> sendEmail.js:135 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

How do I fix this? Thanks.

**sendEmail.js**

```
var courses = ["course1", "course2", "course3", "course4", "Lorem Ipsum - Decoded"];

var courseLoop;
var dataMain;
var dataHTMLMain;
var EMAILcontentDay1,EMAILcontentDay2,EMAILcontentDay3,EMAILcontentDay4,EMAILcontentDay5,EMAILcontentDay6,
EMAILcontentDay7,EMAILcontentDay8,EMAILcontentDay9,EMAILcontentDay10;

var userTime;
var d = new Date();
var utc = d.getUTCHours();
var timeInAmerica = utc - 5;
var timeInAfrica_Europe = utc + 3;
var timeInAsia_Australia = utc + 8;

for(var i=0;i<courses.length;i++){
  courseLoop = courses[i];

/*GETTING EMAIL CONTENT*/
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://calm-cheetah-mwqd.rapidapi.io/get-email-content",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
      "course": courseLoop,
    },
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    dataHTMLMain = data;
    for(var j=0; j<dataHTMLMain.length; j++){
      if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 1){
        EMAILcontentDay1 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "1", EMAILcontentDay1);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 2){
        EMAILcontentDay2 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "2", EMAILcontentDay2);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 3){
        EMAILcontentDay3 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "3", EMAILcontentDay3);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 4){
        EMAILcontentDay4 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "4", EMAILcontentDay4);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 5){
        EMAILcontentDay5 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "5", EMAILcontentDay5);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 6){
        EMAILcontentDay6 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "6", EMAILcontentDay6);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 7){
        EMAILcontentDay7 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "7", EMAILcontentDay7);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 8){
        EMAILcontentDay8 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "8", EMAILcontentDay8);
      }
      else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 9){
        EMAILcontentDay9 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "9", EMAILcontentDay9);
      }
      else if(s[j].day == 10){
        EMAILcontentDay10 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
        sendEmail(dataHTMLMain[j].course, "10", EMAILcontentDay10);
      }
      /*else if(dataHTMLMain[j].day == 10){
        EMAILcontentDay10 = dataHTMLMain[j].HTML;
      }*/

}
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
  })
  .always(function() {
    /* ... */
  });
}
/*END GETTING EMAIL CONTENT*/

/*SENDING OUT THE EMAILS*/
function sendEmail(course, day, content){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://calm-cheetah-mwqd.rapidapi.io/get-day",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
      "course": course,
    }
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    dataMain = data;
    for(var j=0; j<dataMain.length; j++){

//  if(userTime == 24){
    if(dataMain[j].day == day){
      jQuery.ajax({

        url: "http://calm-cheetah-mwqd.rapidapi.io/send-emails-main",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: {
          "email": dataMain[j].email,
          "course": course,
          "HTML": content,
        },
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
        console.log(data);
        //console.log(dataMain[j].email)


              jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://calm-cheetah-mwqd.rapidapi.io/update-day",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: {
                  "email": dataMain[j].email, //problem!
                  "day": (parseInt(dataMain[j].day) + 1), //problem!
                },
              })
              .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
                console.log(data);
              })
              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
              })
              .always(function() {
                /* ... */
              });


      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
      })
      .always(function() {
        /* ... */
      });

    }





//  } //time check end
  }

})

  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
  })
  .always(function() {
    /* ... */
  });

}
```